# How to use verb after word "but"

Tags: verbs, syntactic-analysis, conjunctions

Is given sentence correct?

> "I tried my best to convince her but failed."

In some book, I read we use first form of verb after *but*. So the sentence given above is correct, or not?

Comment: You need a comma after 'her'

Answer (score 2):

Short story:  It is correct.

In English, we often eliminate repeated parts of parallel constructions.  That is, you wouldn't say *I like apples and I like pears and I like watermelon*; instead,  you would likely say *I like apples, pears, and watermelon*.  The *I like* part is assumed for the pears and watermelon.

Let's break down your sentence to see what we've got.

```
   I tried my best to convince her but failed.
   |   |   '-----' '-------------'  |    |
   |   |      |           |         |    |  
   |  Verb  Adverb  Prepositional   |  Second 
Subject     Phrase      Phrase      |   Verb
                                Conjunction
```

The first part -- *I tried my best to convince her* -- has a subject and verb (*I tried*), along with an adverbial phrase (*my best* which answers the question *how did you try?*) and prepositional phrase (what did you try?  *to convince her*).  We can get rid of those last two bits as they just provide some additional info.  So we're left with *I tried*.

Now lets add back the conjunction and second verb: *I tried but failed.*  Here, it's clearer that the subject, *I*, applies to both verbs.  (If it's still unclear, try swapping conjunctions: *I tried and failed.*)  This is a more succinct version of *I tried but I failed.*

When in doubt, try it without the optional parts and see what you think is correct.

Hope this helps!